# PostgreSQL 15 with plperl: lc_monetary problem (works with Postgresql 9.5)

Tags: postgresql, plperl

I was trying to import a Postgres 9.5 dump into a Postgres 15 database and found that creating the plperl extension changes the behavior with lc_monetary: inserts with columns of type money fail when in the dump: `ERROR: invalid input syntax for type money`
When I run the same inserts in the console after importing the dump, they are fine.
The dump works with Postgres 9.5 but not with Postgres 15.

I reduced the dump to the relevant lines:

```sql
SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET xmloption = content;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

show lc_monetary;

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plperl WITH SCHEMA pg_catalog;

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plpgsql WITH SCHEMA pg_catalog;

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS btree_gist WITH SCHEMA public;

show lc_monetary;

CREATE DOMAIN public.nonnegmoney AS money
    CONSTRAINT nonnegmoney_check CHECK ((VALUE >= (0)::money));

ALTER DOMAIN public.nonnegmoney OWNER TO vms_test;

CREATE TABLE public.vms_test (
     id integer,
     money1 public.nonnegmoney,
     money2 money
);

ALTER TABLE public.vms_test OWNER TO vms_test;

insert into public.vms_test (id, money1, money2) values (1, '€ 0,00', '€ 0,00'); -- <=== fails here
insert into public.vms_test (id, money1, money2) values (2, '€ 625,00', '€ 625,00');

REVOKE ALL ON TABLE public.vms_test FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL ON TABLE public.vms_test FROM vms_test;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE public.vms_test TO vms_test;
```

If I disable the plperl extension creation line, the dump works.
If I enable the line with plperl extension creation and disable the inserts, the dump works too - and - as I said - if I run those inserts afterwards, they work.
Also, it doesn't matter if I use `--column-inserts` for the dump or not.
(Changing the database is not an option)

Maybe it's a problem how I create the docker container.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:15
USER root
RUN localedef -i de_AT -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias de_AT.UTF-8
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install perl
RUN apt-get -y install postgresql-plperl-15
ENV LANG de_AT.utf8
```

docker-compose:

```
version: '2'

services:

  vmspostgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: postgres/Dockerfile
    container_name: vms-postgres-15
    ports:
      - "5439:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./_postgresdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./postgres/15-create-dbs.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/15-create-dbs.sh
      - ./postgres/17-monetary-test.sql:/17-monetary-test.sql
      - ./postgres/18-monetary-test.sql.gz:/18-monetary-test.sql.gz
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=vms
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxx
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    command: ["postgres", "-c", "log_statement=all"]
```

This is the database log with enabled `CREATE EXTENSION plperl` line (Sorry it's in German but I hope you can get an idea of what it means):

```
2023-01-09 10:11:55 /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: sourcing /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/15-create-dbs.sh
2023-01-09 10:11:55 === 17-monetary-test.sql ===
2023-01-09 10:11:55 2023-01-09 09:11:55.189 UTC [61] LOG:  Anweisung: CREATE ROLE vms_test LOGIN
2023-01-09 10:11:55   PASSWORD 'vms_test'
2023-01-09 10:11:55   NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION;
2023-01-09 10:11:55 CREATE ROLE
2023-01-09 10:11:55 2023-01-09 09:11:55.206 UTC [61] LOG:  Anweisung: create database vms_test with owner vms_test LC_COLLATE = 'de_AT.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE = 'de_AT.UTF-8' TEMPLATE template0;
2023-01-09 10:11:55 CREATE DATABASE
2023-01-09 10:11:55 2023-01-09 09:11:55.436 UTC [61] LOG:  Anweisung: set datestyle = 'iso, ymd';
2023-01-09 10:11:55 SET
2023-01-09 10:11:55 2023-01-09 09:11:55.436 UTC [61] LOG:  Anweisung: set lc_messages = 'en_US.UTF-8';
2023-01-09 10:11:55 SET
2023-01-09 10:11:55 2023-01-09 09:11:55.436 UTC [61] LOG:  statement: set lc_monetary = 'de_AT.UTF-8';
2023-01-09 10:11:55 SET
2023-01-09 10:11:55 2023-01-09 09:11:55.436 UTC [61] LOG:  statement: set lc_numeric = 'de_AT.UTF-8';
2023-01-09 10:11:55 SET
2023-01-09 10:11:55 2023-01-09 09:11:55.437 UTC [61] LOG:  statement: set lc_time = 'de_AT.UTF-8';
2023-01-09 10:11:55 SET
2023-01-09 10:11:55 2023-01-09 09:11:55.437 UTC [61] LOG:  statement: set default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.german';
2023-01-09 10:11:55 SET
2023-01-09 10:11:55 2023-01-09 09:11:55.438 UTC [61] LOG:  statement: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE vms_test TO vms_test;
2023-01-09 10:11:55 GRANT
2023-01-09 10:11:55 
2023-01-09 10:11:55 === 18-monetry-test.sql.gz ===
2023-01-09 10:11:55 2023-01-09 09:11:55.522 UTC [64] LOG:  Anweisung: SET statement_timeout = 0;
2023-01-09 10:11:55 SET
2023-01-09 10:11:55 2023-01-09 09:11:55.523 UTC [64] LOG:  Anweisung: SET lock_timeout = 0;
2023-01-09 10:11:55 SET
2023-01-09 10:11:55 2023-01-09 09:11:55.523 UTC [64] LOG:  Anweisung: SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
2023-01-09 10:11:55 SET
2023-01-09 10:11:55 2023-01-09 09:11:55.523 UTC [64] LOG:  Anweisung: SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
2023-01-09 10:11:55 SET
2023-01-09 10:11:55 2023-01-09 09:11:55.523 UTC [64] LOG:  Anweisung: SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
2023-01-09 10:11:55  set_config 
2023-01-09 10:11:55 ------------
2023-01-09 10:11:55  
2023-01-09 10:11:55 (1 Zeile)
2023-01-09 10:11:55 
2023-01-09 10:11:55 2023-01-09 09:11:55.524 UTC [64] LOG:  Anweisung: SET check_function_bodies = false;
2023-01-09 10:11:55 SET
2023-01-09 10:11:55 2023-01-09 09:11:55.525 UTC [64] LOG:  Anweisung: SET xmloption = content;
2023-01-09 10:11:55 SET
2023-01-09 10:11:55 2023-01-09 09:11:55.525 UTC [64] LOG:  Anweisung: SET client_min_messages = warning;
2023-01-09 10:11:55 SET
2023-01-09 10:11:55 2023-01-09 09:11:55.526 UTC [64] LOG:  Anweisung: SET row_security = off;
2023-01-09 10:11:55 SET
2023-01-09 10:11:55 2023-01-09 09:11:55.526 UTC [64] LOG:  Anweisung: show lc_monetary;
2023-01-09 10:11:55  lc_monetary 
2023-01-09 10:11:55 -------------
2023-01-09 10:11:55  de_AT.utf8
2023-01-09 10:11:55 (1 Zeile)
2023-01-09 10:11:55 
2023-01-09 10:11:55 2023-01-09 09:11:55.526 UTC [64] LOG:  Anweisung: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plperl WITH SCHEMA pg_catalog;
2023-01-09 10:11:55 CREATE EXTENSION
2023-01-09 10:11:55 2023-01-09 09:11:55.551 UTC [64] LOG:  Anweisung: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plpgsql WITH SCHEMA pg_catalog;
2023-01-09 10:11:55 CREATE EXTENSION
2023-01-09 10:11:55 2023-01-09 09:11:55.551 UTC [64] LOG:  Anweisung: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS btree_gist WITH SCHEMA public;
2023-01-09 10:11:55 CREATE EXTENSION
2023-01-09 10:11:55 2023-01-09 09:11:55.610 UTC [64] LOG:  Anweisung: show lc_monetary;
2023-01-09 10:11:55  lc_monetary 
2023-01-09 10:11:55 -------------
2023-01-09 10:11:55  de_AT.utf8
2023-01-09 10:11:55 (1 Zeile)
2023-01-09 10:11:55 
2023-01-09 10:11:55 2023-01-09 09:11:55.611 UTC [64] LOG:  Anweisung: CREATE DOMAIN public.nonnegmoney AS money
2023-01-09 10:11:55     CONSTRAINT nonnegmoney_check CHECK ((VALUE >= (0)::money));
2023-01-09 10:11:55 CREATE DOMAIN
2023-01-09 10:11:55 2023-01-09 09:11:55.612 UTC [64] LOG:  Anweisung: ALTER DOMAIN public.nonnegmoney OWNER TO vms_test;
2023-01-09 10:11:55 ALTER DOMAIN
2023-01-09 10:11:55 2023-01-09 09:11:55.613 UTC [64] LOG:  Anweisung: CREATE TABLE public.vms_test (
2023-01-09 10:11:55      id integer,
2023-01-09 10:11:55      money1 public.nonnegmoney,
2023-01-09 10:11:55      money2 money
2023-01-09 10:11:55 );
2023-01-09 10:11:55 CREATE TABLE
2023-01-09 10:11:55 2023-01-09 09:11:55.616 UTC [64] LOG:  Anweisung: ALTER TABLE public.vms_test OWNER TO vms_test;
2023-01-09 10:11:55 ALTER TABLE
2023-01-09 10:11:55 2023-01-09 09:11:55.617 UTC [64] LOG:  Anweisung: insert into public.vms_test (id, money1, money2) values (1, '€ 0,00', '€ 0,00');
2023-01-09 10:11:55 2023-01-09 09:11:55.617 UTC [64] FEHLER:  ungültige Eingabesyntax für Typ money: »€ 0,00« bei Zeichen 61
2023-01-09 10:11:55 2023-01-09 09:11:55.617 UTC [64] ANWEISUNG:  insert into public.vms_test (id, money1, money2) values (1, '€ 0,00', '€ 0,00');
2023-01-09 10:11:55 FEHLER:  ungültige Eingabesyntax für Typ money: »€ 0,00«
2023-01-09 10:11:55 ZEILE 1: ...o public.vms_test (id, money1, money2) values (1, '€ 0,00', ...
2023-01-09 10:11:55                                                               ^
```

This is the database log with disabled `CREATE EXTENSION plperl` line:

```
2023-01-09 10:15:11 /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: sourcing /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/15-create-dbs.sh
2023-01-09 10:15:11 === 17-monetary-test.sql ===
2023-01-09 10:15:11 2023-01-09 09:15:11.402 UTC [60] LOG:  Anweisung: CREATE ROLE vms_test LOGIN
2023-01-09 10:15:11   PASSWORD 'vms_test'
2023-01-09 10:15:11   NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION;
2023-01-09 10:15:11 CREATE ROLE
2023-01-09 10:15:11 2023-01-09 09:15:11.419 UTC [60] LOG:  Anweisung: create database vms_test with owner vms_test LC_COLLATE = 'de_AT.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE = 'de_AT.UTF-8' TEMPLATE template0;
2023-01-09 10:15:11 CREATE DATABASE
2023-01-09 10:15:11 2023-01-09 09:15:11.653 UTC [60] LOG:  Anweisung: set datestyle = 'iso, ymd';
2023-01-09 10:15:11 SET
2023-01-09 10:15:11 2023-01-09 09:15:11.653 UTC [60] LOG:  Anweisung: set lc_messages = 'en_US.UTF-8';
2023-01-09 10:15:11 SET
2023-01-09 10:15:11 2023-01-09 09:15:11.653 UTC [60] LOG:  statement: set lc_monetary = 'de_AT.UTF-8';
2023-01-09 10:15:11 SET
2023-01-09 10:15:11 2023-01-09 09:15:11.653 UTC [60] LOG:  statement: set lc_numeric = 'de_AT.UTF-8';
2023-01-09 10:15:11 SET
2023-01-09 10:15:11 2023-01-09 09:15:11.654 UTC [60] LOG:  statement: set lc_time = 'de_AT.UTF-8';
2023-01-09 10:15:11 SET
2023-01-09 10:15:11 2023-01-09 09:15:11.654 UTC [60] LOG:  statement: set default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.german';
2023-01-09 10:15:11 SET
2023-01-09 10:15:11 2023-01-09 09:15:11.655 UTC [60] LOG:  statement: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE vms_test TO vms_test;
2023-01-09 10:15:11 GRANT
2023-01-09 10:15:11 
2023-01-09 10:15:11 === 18-monetry-test.sql.gz ===
2023-01-09 10:15:11 2023-01-09 09:15:11.743 UTC [63] LOG:  Anweisung: SET statement_timeout = 0;
2023-01-09 10:15:11 SET
2023-01-09 10:15:11 2023-01-09 09:15:11.743 UTC [63] LOG:  Anweisung: SET lock_timeout = 0;
2023-01-09 10:15:11 SET
2023-01-09 10:15:11 2023-01-09 09:15:11.743 UTC [63] LOG:  Anweisung: SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
2023-01-09 10:15:11 SET
2023-01-09 10:15:11 2023-01-09 09:15:11.743 UTC [63] LOG:  Anweisung: SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
2023-01-09 10:15:11 SET
2023-01-09 10:15:11 2023-01-09 09:15:11.743 UTC [63] LOG:  Anweisung: SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
2023-01-09 10:15:11  set_config 
2023-01-09 10:15:11 ------------
2023-01-09 10:15:11  
2023-01-09 10:15:11 (1 Zeile)
2023-01-09 10:15:11 
2023-01-09 10:15:11 2023-01-09 09:15:11.744 UTC [63] LOG:  Anweisung: SET check_function_bodies = false;
2023-01-09 10:15:11 SET
2023-01-09 10:15:11 2023-01-09 09:15:11.744 UTC [63] LOG:  Anweisung: SET xmloption = content;
2023-01-09 10:15:11 SET
2023-01-09 10:15:11 2023-01-09 09:15:11.744 UTC [63] LOG:  Anweisung: SET client_min_messages = warning;
2023-01-09 10:15:11 SET
2023-01-09 10:15:11 2023-01-09 09:15:11.744 UTC [63] LOG:  Anweisung: SET row_security = off;
2023-01-09 10:15:11 SET
2023-01-09 10:15:11 2023-01-09 09:15:11.744 UTC [63] LOG:  Anweisung: show lc_monetary;
2023-01-09 10:15:11  lc_monetary 
2023-01-09 10:15:11 -------------
2023-01-09 10:15:11  de_AT.utf8
2023-01-09 10:15:11 (1 Zeile)
2023-01-09 10:15:11 
2023-01-09 10:15:11 2023-01-09 09:15:11.744 UTC [63] LOG:  Anweisung: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plpgsql WITH SCHEMA pg_catalog;
2023-01-09 10:15:11 CREATE EXTENSION
2023-01-09 10:15:11 2023-01-09 09:15:11.745 UTC [63] LOG:  Anweisung: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS btree_gist WITH SCHEMA public;
2023-01-09 10:15:11 CREATE EXTENSION
2023-01-09 10:15:11 2023-01-09 09:15:11.815 UTC [63] LOG:  Anweisung: show lc_monetary;
2023-01-09 10:15:11  lc_monetary 
2023-01-09 10:15:11 -------------
2023-01-09 10:15:11  de_AT.utf8
2023-01-09 10:15:11 (1 Zeile)
2023-01-09 10:15:11 
2023-01-09 10:15:11 2023-01-09 09:15:11.815 UTC [63] LOG:  Anweisung: CREATE DOMAIN public.nonnegmoney AS money
2023-01-09 10:15:11     CONSTRAINT nonnegmoney_check CHECK ((VALUE >= (0)::money));
2023-01-09 10:15:11 CREATE DOMAIN
2023-01-09 10:15:11 2023-01-09 09:15:11.816 UTC [63] LOG:  Anweisung: ALTER DOMAIN public.nonnegmoney OWNER TO vms_test;
2023-01-09 10:15:11 ALTER DOMAIN
2023-01-09 10:15:11 2023-01-09 09:15:11.817 UTC [63] LOG:  Anweisung: CREATE TABLE public.vms_test (
2023-01-09 10:15:11      id integer,
2023-01-09 10:15:11      money1 public.nonnegmoney,
2023-01-09 10:15:11      money2 money
2023-01-09 10:15:11 );
2023-01-09 10:15:11 CREATE TABLE
2023-01-09 10:15:11 2023-01-09 09:15:11.818 UTC [63] LOG:  Anweisung: ALTER TABLE public.vms_test OWNER TO vms_test;
2023-01-09 10:15:11 ALTER TABLE
2023-01-09 10:15:11 2023-01-09 09:15:11.819 UTC [63] LOG:  Anweisung: insert into public.vms_test (id, money1, money2) values (1, '€ 0,00', '€ 0,00');
2023-01-09 10:15:11 INSERT 0 1
2023-01-09 10:15:11 2023-01-09 09:15:11.820 UTC [63] LOG:  Anweisung: insert into public.vms_test (id, money1, money2) values (2, '€ 625,00', '€ 625,00');
2023-01-09 10:15:11 INSERT 0 1
2023-01-09 10:15:11 2023-01-09 09:15:11.820 UTC [63] LOG:  Anweisung: REVOKE ALL ON TABLE public.vms_test FROM PUBLIC;
2023-01-09 10:15:11 REVOKE
2023-01-09 10:15:11 2023-01-09 09:15:11.820 UTC [63] LOG:  Anweisung: REVOKE ALL ON TABLE public.vms_test FROM vms_test;
2023-01-09 10:15:11 REVOKE
2023-01-09 10:15:11 2023-01-09 09:15:11.821 UTC [63] LOG:  Anweisung: GRANT ALL ON TABLE public.vms_test TO vms_test;
2023-01-09 10:15:11 GRANT
2023-01-09 10:15:11 
2023-01-09 10:15:11 
2023-01-09 10:15:11 2023-01-09 09:15:11.827 UTC [49] LOG:  schnelles Herunterfahren verlangt
2023-01-09 10:15:11 warte auf Herunterfahren des Servers...2023-01-09 09:15:11.828 UTC [49] LOG:  etwaige aktive Transaktionen werden abgebrochen
2023-01-09 10:15:11 2023-01-09 09:15:11.832 UTC [49] LOG:  Background-Worker »logical replication launcher« (PID 55) beendete mit Status 1
2023-01-09 10:15:11 .2023-01-09 09:15:11.835 UTC [50] LOG:  fahre herunter
2023-01-09 10:15:11 2023-01-09 09:15:11.836 UTC [50] LOG:  Checkpoint beginnt: shutdown immediate
2023-01-09 10:15:12 2023-01-09 09:15:12.013 UTC [50] LOG:  Checkpoint komplett: 973 Puffer geschrieben (5.9%); 0 WAL-Datei(en) hinzugefügt, 0 entfernt, 0 wiederverwendet; Schreiben=0,083 s, Sync=0,091 s, gesamt=0,179 s; sync. Dateien=258, längste=0,003 s, Durchschnitt=0.001 s; Entfernung=4905 kB, Schätzung=4905 kB
2023-01-09 10:15:12 2023-01-09 09:15:12.056 UTC [49] LOG:  Datenbanksystem ist heruntergefahren
2023-01-09 10:15:12  fertig
2023-01-09 10:15:12 Server angehalten
2023-01-09 10:15:12 
2023-01-09 10:15:12 PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
2023-01-09 10:15:12 
2023-01-09 10:15:12 2023-01-09 09:15:12.188 UTC [1] LOG:  PostgreSQL 15.1 (Debian 15.1-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit startet
2023-01-09 10:15:12 2023-01-09 09:15:12.188 UTC [1] LOG:  erwarte Verbindungen auf IPv4-Adresse »0.0.0.0«, Port 5432
2023-01-09 10:15:12 2023-01-09 09:15:12.188 UTC [1] LOG:  erwarte Verbindungen auf IPv6-Adresse »::«, Port 5432
2023-01-09 10:15:12 2023-01-09 09:15:12.191 UTC [1] LOG:  erwarte Verbindungen auf Unix-Socket »/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432«
2023-01-09 10:15:12 2023-01-09 09:15:12.204 UTC [68] LOG:  Datenbanksystem wurde am 2023-01-09 09:15:12 UTC heruntergefahren
2023-01-09 10:15:12 2023-01-09 09:15:12.220 UTC [1] LOG:  Datenbanksystem ist bereit, um Verbindungen anzunehmen
```

This is the import script which is executed in the docker container:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

echo "=== 17-monetary-test.sql ==="
psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username postgres --dbname postgres -f ../17-monetary-test.sql; echo;
echo "=== 18-monetry-test.sql.gz ==="
gunzip -c ../18-monetary-test.sql.gz | psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username postgres --dbname vms_test; echo;
```

What do you think?

**"SOLUTION"**

I haven't found any real solution to this specific problem. All attempts with different postgres versions were unsuccessful, both with docker and directly on my Linux system.
Even if I execute all statements of the dump on the console, there is ultimately a problem with the import of larger amounts of money, because on newer Linux systems the thousands separator of `lc_monetary` for the locale `de_AT` has been changed from a normal space (`<U0020>`) to a non-breakable-space (`<U202F>`).

Since the official Docker container for postgres-9.5 is no longer supported, I got the Dockerfile for version 9.5 from the postgres git history, changed the apt directories to the archive directories and now have a running postgres-9.5 docker version, into which I can import the old database.
For our software upgrade to a current postgresql version, we will change all money columns to a numeric type!

Thank you for your help (especially @AdrianKlaver)

Comment: Could your share the result from this statement: SHOW lc_monetary;

Comment: The use of the `money` data type is [discouraged](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_money) , so maybe this is a good time to change the column to `numeric`

Comment: 1) What version of `pg_dump` did you use to dump the Postgres 9.5 instance the one from 9.5 or the one from 15? 2) Add the complete error message to your question.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I added two lines of show lc_monetary and also added both log outputs (in German)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I know this, but the application is a huge legacy application with a lot of business logic in the database (hundreds of procedures and triggers). Unfortunately changing the data type is not an option I have.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I used the pg_dump of the remote source server (9.5) - I added the docker import script in my first post.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Questions: 1) To be clear using `COPY` instead of `INSERT` to populate tables fails also? 2) When you dumped the 9.5 instance did you dump use the 9.5 version of `pg_dump` or the 15 version? If the 9.5 version then try the 15 version of `pg_dump` to dump the 9.5 instance. 3) Why the two scripts: 17-monetary-test.sql and 18-monetary-test.sql and what is in them?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver 
1) the original dump uses `COPY` and fails too
2) I dumped with the 9.5 `pg_dump` - I'll try to dump with version 15 tomorrow
3) Please look at the log output - there you can see where the scripts start and what statements are in them (first script is supposed to create the database, second script is the dump of pg_dump - the last block of code is the shell script that runs the scripts)

How are you trying to reproduce? With Docker? If so, maybe you could provide your Dockerfile?

Comment: 1) I avoid Docker like the plague, if for other reason then the amount of times it shows up as the problem here. 2) Why not do `pg_dump -C ...` where  per here [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) `-C`  includes the `CREATE DATABASE ...` at beginning of file. Then would only need to have one file. You would then need to do `psql -d postgres ...` to use the `postgres` database to bootstrap the creation of the dumped database. Actually `-d` could point at any database you can connect to.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thanks for your opinion. 

Even if I put all the scripts in one file (even the `create database`) it makes no difference. Also, I found out that the problem is not limited to `lc_monetary`. It also affects `lc_numeric`. E.g. `SELECT to_number('1,513.4','9999D99');` shows `1513.4` on `postgres 9.5` as expected. But with plperl enabled and `postgres 15` it shows `1.51`

I don't know what else can be the reason if you can't reproduce it. Could it be the perl installation or the plperl version?

Comment: It is interesting that afterwards it works via console with the created database. That must have something to do with how the scripts are executed, right?

Comment: `plperl` should not have anything to do with `lc_monetary` and `lc_numeric`. This `SELECT to_number('1,513.4','9999D99') 1.51` is expected with `lc_numeric  = 'de_AT.UTF-8';` With that locale you would need `SELECT to_number('1.513,4','9999D99'); 1513.4`. To your question add the complete `pg_dump` command you are using. Also what is `lc_numeric` and `lc_monetary` set to in the 9.5 instance.

Comment: Hmm, I ran into somewhat related issues when I did a plain text dump/restore from a 14 --> 15 instance. When I did a  `-Fc` dump and used `pg_restore` the issues went away. Not sure what is going on yet. You might try the custom format and see if it works in your case also.